# Combine aggregated variables into one variable in R

Tags: r

I am using this code to combine 100s of dates into their respective months:

```
cpkmonthly <- aggregate(mydf$AVG, na.rm=TRUE, list(month=months(as.Date(mydf$DATETIME))), mean)
```

This is the output in R:

```
> cpkmonthly
   month         x
1  April 0.4583167
2 August 0.4416660
3   July 0.4436665
4   June 0.4435551
5  March 0.4654443
6    May 0.4523338
```

I am looking for a way to combine certian months into quarters instead.

```
Jan-March = q1
April-June = q2
July-Sep = q3
Oct-Dec = q4
```

Is there a way to do this?

The output should look something like this:

```
> cpkquarterly
   quarter         x
1       q1 0.4583167
2       q2 0.4416660
3       q3 0.4436665
4       q4 0.4435551
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `zoo` package has a function to do this:

```
library(zoo)
as.yearqtr("2012-06", "%Y-%m")

# [1] "2012 Q2"
```

Comment: Thanks! This is a really helpful package. Is there also a way to declare where to start q1? For example, I sometimes want q1 to start in July.

Comment: not directly.  You could change the output by mapping Q1 > Q3 etc. Or look at the source code for that function and write your own with the shifted outputs.

Answer (score 1):

It's not clear what you want:

```
> require(data.table)
> cpkmonthly <- data.table(month=c("April", "August", "July","June","March","May"),
+ x=c(0.4583167,0.4416660,0.4436665,0.4435551,0.4654443,0.4523338)
+ )
> 
> cpkmonthly
    month         x
1:  April 0.4583167
2: August 0.4416660
3:   July 0.4436665
4:   June 0.4435551
5:  March 0.4654443
6:    May 0.4523338
> 
> quart <- data.table(month=month.name,quarter=rep(1:4, each=3),key="month")
> 
> ###if you just want each row assigned to a quarter:
> quart[cpkmonthly]
    month quarter         x
1:  April       2 0.4583167
2: August       3 0.4416660
3:   July       3 0.4436665
4:   June       2 0.4435551
5:  March       1 0.4654443
6:    May       2 0.4523338
> 
> ###if you want to aggregate in various ways:
> 
> quart[cpkmonthly][,list(x.avg=mean(x),x.max=max(x),x.1=x[1]),by=quarter][order(quarter)]
   quarter     x.avg     x.max       x.1
1:       1 0.4654443 0.4654443 0.4654443
2:       2 0.4514019 0.4583167 0.4583167
3:       3 0.4426663 0.4436665 0.4416660
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem, but my company has a calendar in which quarters start & end on irregular dates. Here's how I tackled this within my own data. Note that my data set contains > 5MM rows so I'm using [`data.table`](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/data.table/index.html) instead of data.frame.

```
# My data is contained in the myDT data.table.
# Dates are contained in the date column.

require("data.table")

Q1FY14 <- myDT[ which(date >= "2013-02-02" & date <= "2013-05-03"), ]
Q2FY14 <- myDT[ which(date >= "2013-05-04" & date <= "2013-08-02"), ]
Q3FY14 <- myDT[ which(date >= "2013-08-03" & date <= "2013-11-01"), ]
Q4FY14 <- myDT[ which(date >= "2013-11-02" & date <= "2014-01-31"), ]
Q1FY15 <- myDT[ which(date >= "2014-02-01" & date <= "2014-05-02"), ]

# Create new vectors.
Q1.14 <- rep("Q1 FY14", nrow(Q1FY14))
Q2.14 <- rep("Q2 FY14", nrow(Q2FY14))
Q3.14 <- rep("Q3 FY14", nrow(Q3FY14))
Q4.14 <- rep("Q4 FY14", nrow(Q4FY14))
Q1.15 <- rep("Q1 FY15", nrow(Q1FY15))

# Add each of my new vectors to their associate data.table.
Q1FY14$quarter <- Q1.14
Q2FY14$quarter <- Q2.14
Q3FY14$quarter <- Q3.14
Q4FY14$quarter <- Q4.14
Q1FY15$quarter <- Q1.15

# Bring it all together.
newDT <- rbind(Q1FY14, Q2FY14)
newDT <- rbind(newDT, Q3FY14)
newDT <- rbind(newDT, Q4FY14)
newDT <- rbind(newDT, Q1FY15)

# Clean up data.
rm(Q1FY14, Q2FY14, Q3FY14, Q4FY14, Q1FY15, Q1.14, Q2.14, Q3.14, Q4.14, Q1.15)
```

That added the correct quarter for each row. I needed a couple of other minor tweaks to make it usable.

```
# Change the column order so that quarter appears next to date.
setcolorder(newDT, c("date", "quarter", ...))

# Change the quarter column to factors.
newDT$quarter <- factor(newDT$quarter)
```